# highchart xaxis value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts for my charts and it works very well.

But now I want the value of my mysql results. What i tried looks like this:

```
xAxis: {
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        month: '%b'   
    }



data: [<?

    //verkoopfacturen tot 30 dagem oud
    $query = "SELECT SUM(VerkoopfactBedrag) AS bedrag, DATE_FORMAT(VerkoopfactDatum, '%m') AS date
    FROM verkoopfacturen WHERE Verkoopfact_UserId = {$_COOKIE['customer_id']} AND VerkoopfactDatum BETWEEN '{$year}-01-01' AND '{$year}-12-30'
    GROUP BY MONTH(VerkoopfactDatum)";
    $sql = mysql_query("$query"); 
    while ($fill = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
    { 
        $bedrag = $fill['bedrag'];
        $date = $fill['date'];


        echo '[';
        echo $date.',';
        echo $bedrag;
        echo '],';
    }

    ?>]
```

The problem is now that I get the months in decimals

Answer (score 0):

You can use the actual date on your xAxis, and let HighCharts render it. See xAxis - dateTimeLabelFormats in the [API reference](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--dateTimeLabelFormats).

Comment: I edit my post with the example i tried but now i get decimals value

Comment: If you use this, you should pass date as a UTC date (so remove the DATE_FORMAT from the query).

Comment: do you have a little example of that?

Comment: There are many examples in the documentation, this is [one of them](http://jsfiddle.net/CAKQH/310/).

Comment: data looks like this: data: [[Date.UTC(2011,06,24), 10003.94],[Date.UTC(2011,08,26), -3293.95],[Date.UTC(2011,09,20), 8281.28],[Date.UTC(2011,10,06), 1000.80],[Date.UTC(2011,11,03), 24.04],]

Comment: You only set month, you may have to reset the others (day, week, etc.) to an empty string.

Comment: How can i reset the others to an empty string? Do I have to do this in the series data or in the dateTimeLabelFormats? Sorry for all these questions but i really need to know. Reset the dateTimeLabelFormats to empty didn't work for me

Comment: Just as you set month, but then an empty string.

Comment: When i do this: dateTimeLabelFormats: {
       day: '',
       week: '',
       month: '%b',
       year: ''
      } I get really weird results like 1,307,923

Comment: Your example looks fine to me (Opera 10). You can use the formatter instead. See the [documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis-labels--formatter) and [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/grVFk/7/). I think you need to take more time studying the documentation and examples.

Comment: It worked with the formatter. The only thing now is that when i use width 100% of my screen so he is very width i get the dates several time like jul jul aug aug aug aug aug sept sept etc...

Comment: I know you can use 'step', but am not sure if that would solve your issue. Perhaps you're better of posting on the highcharts forum.